# Не могу понять, что не так в этом коде

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

[image]
Вот фотография кода. Сижу и не могу понять в чем проблема. Пытаюсь написать код для управления персонажа на телефоне по этому видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urU6u0446qA&t=207s. Я уже пробывал и явно и не явно, реализовать интерфейсы IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler. Студия перестает распознавать код как ошибку если реализовать интерфейсы, но Unity все равно считает что интерфейсы не реализованы.

Код:

```
public class btns : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public void OnPoniterDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 6f);
    }

    public void OnPoniterUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 6f);
    }

}
```

Comment: Отправьте код в блоке кода а не картинкой, объясните что вы попробовали и что не получилось. Задавайте [нормальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) тогда и поговорим.

Comment: Кликните один раз по имени подчеркнутого красным интерфейса вам высветится сообщение с информацией о причине ошибки, СКОРЕЕ всего не объявлены методы необходимые для реализации интерфейса. На этот случай, как любят говорить в видео которые вы смотрите, "лайфхак": в этом всплывающем окошке будет ссылка "возможные решения"(или как то так), в ней можно выбрать что то на подобие "реализовать интерфейс явно"

Comment: Будьте внимательны! Для Интерфейса необходимы "OnPointer"-методы. А у Вас *"Ponter"*

Comment: @Александр Даниловский спасибо за замечание, но проблема не решилась

Comment: В смысле не решилась? Исправленный код в студию с новыми ошибками!

Comment: @Александр Даниловский пойду по новой учится писать, походу совсем разучился. Проблема решилась. Спасибо!

Comment: @Александр Даниловский теперь бы понять где кнопка отметить правильный ответ?

Comment: А ответа как сущность и не было. Были комментарии. Предлагаю в поле ниже Вам самому ответить на собственный вопрос/проблему. Это может оказаться полезным другим, кто может столкнуться с подобным (опечатки при работе с реализацией интерфейсов)

Answer (score 1):

В итоге проблема оказалась в очень простой вещи, в написании названия функции. Вместо Pointer я написал Ponter. Что доказывает что нужно быть внимательнее к написанию.